# Can I read a constexpr value or mpl int from a binary?

Tags: c++, debug-symbols

Suppose I have some program:

```
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>

using MyValue = boost::mpl::int<4>;
constexpr const int myValue = 4;
int main()
{
  // stuff that uses MyValue and myValue here
  return 0;
}
```

What is the best way to retrieve either `MyValue` or `myValue` from the resulting debug binary in a compiler-agnostic way on a unix system? This question is as much about what is required to generate the binary as it is about how to get the data back out.

Comment: *Compiler-agnostic*? I don't think there's such a way, since this most likely falls far beyond the scope of any C++ standard.

Comment: @Frxstrem I understand that it's beyond the standard, but there are tools in unix (e.g. `objdump`) that can retrieve information from symbol tables. I was hoping to make use of something similar. Doing a `grep` through the symbol table is obviously an option, but I was hoping for something simpler/cleaner if possible, although I will understand if that's the only way to do this.

Comment: @quant Can I ask why would you want to do this? Is it an xy problem?

Comment: @vsoftco yes it probably is. I have a piece of software from which I need to read a meta-int (such as `boost::mpl::int_`). I don't really have the luxury of finding a cleaner solution at this stage, although clearly doing this is not ideal.

Comment: No decent optimizing compiler will emit either into the binary. One is a unused const variable with internal linkage, and the other is a type that is not in the signature of anything anywhere.

Comment: @T.C. I've adjusted the code and description as per your comments; The binary can be compiled without optimizations and, in any case, the types/values are used.